# Generating a list of distinct (distant, by edit distance) words by filtering

Tags: python, algorithm, duplicates, similarity, edit-distance

I have a long (> 1000 items) list of words, from which I would like to remove words that are "too similar" to other words, until the remaining words are all "significantly different".  For example, so that no two words are within an edit distance D.

I do not need a unique solution, and it doesn't have to be exactly optimal, but it should be reasonably quick (in Python) and not discard way too many entries.

How can I achieve this?  Thanks.

Edit: to be clear, I can google for a python routine that measures edit distance.  The problem is how to do this efficiently, and, perhaps, in some way that finds a "natural" value of D.  Maybe by constructing some kind of trie from all words and then pruning?

Comment: Have a look at [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module.

Comment: How does that solve the O(n^2) comparison that is the underlying problem here?

Comment: The trouble is that a bk-tree is not suited for this problem, since it identifies items that are close to newly inserted nodes, not items within the tree that are close to each other.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: A BK-tree would be fine.  For each word, compute the minimum distance from that word to a word in the tree.  If it is at least equal to D, then insert the word into the tree.  When you are done, you have a BK tree containing nodes with minimum distance D from each other.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: thanks for the suggestion- implementation is below and works pretty well!

Comment: You may find something in the [FAdo library](http://fado.dcc.fc.up.pt/) (or at least some reference implementations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `bk-tree`, and before each item is added check that it is not within distance D of any others (thanks to @DietrichEpp in the comments for this idea.

You can use [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572156-bk-tree/) for a bk-tree (though any similar recipes are easily modified). Simply make two changes: change the line:

```
def __init__(self, items, distance, usegc=False):
```

to

```
def __init__(self, items, distance, threshold=0, usegc=False):
```

And change the line

```
        if el not in self.nodes: # do not add duplicates
```

to

```
        if (el not in self.nodes and
            (threshold == None or len(self.find(el, threshold)) == 0)):
```

This makes sure there are no duplicates when an item is added. Then, the code to remove duplicates from a list is simply:

```
from Levenshtein import distance
from bktree import BKtree
def remove_duplicates(lst, threshold):
    tr = BKtree(iter(lst), distance, threshold)
    return tr.nodes.keys()
```

*Note* that this relies on the [python-Levenshtein](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) package for its distance function, which is much faster than the one provided by bk-tree. python-Levenshtein has C-compiled components, but it's worth the installation.

---

Finally, I set up a performance test with an increasing number of words (grabbed randomly from `/usr/share/dict/words`) and graphed the amount of time each took to run:

```
import random
import time
from Levenshtein import distance
from bktree import BKtree

with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as inf:
    word_list = [l[:-1] for l in inf]

def remove_duplicates(lst, threshold):
    tr = BKtree(iter(lst), distance, threshold)
    return tr.nodes.keys()

def time_remove_duplicates(n, threshold):
    """Test using n words"""
    nwords = random.sample(word_list, n)
    t = time.time()
    newlst = remove_duplicates(nwords, threshold)
    return len(newlst), time.time() - t

ns = range(1000, 16000, 2000)
results = [time_remove_duplicates(n, 3) for n in ns]
lengths, timings = zip(*results)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(ns, timings)
plt.xlabel("Number of strings")
plt.ylabel("Time (s)")
plt.savefig("number_vs_time.pdf")
```

[image]

Without confirming it mathematically, I don't think it's quadratic, and I think it might actually be `n log n`, which would make sense if inserting into a bk-tree is a log time operation. Most notably, it runs pretty quickly with under 5000 strings, which hopefully is the OP's goal (and it's *reasonable* with 15000, which a traditional for loop solution would not be).

Comment: thanks, but that's O(n^2) (i think?).  i was hoping for something smarter.

Comment: @andrewcooke: I'm guessing it's still faster than a nested for loop approach, but yes.

Comment: oh, thanks, this looks good. (comment for O(n^2) was for previous version of this post).

Answer (score 2):

Tries will not be helpful, nor will hash maps.  They are simply not useful for spatial, high-dimensional problems like this one.

But the real problem here is the ill-specified requirement of "efficient".  How fast is "efficient"?

```
import Levenshtein

def simple(corpus, distance):
    words = []
    while corpus:
        center = corpus[0]
        words.append(center)
        corpus = [word for word in corpus
                  if Levenshtein.distance(center, word) >= distance]
    return words
```

I ran this on 10,000 words selected uniformly from the "American English" dictionary I have on my hard drive, looking for sets with a distance of 5, yielding around 2,000 entries.

```
real    0m2.558s
user    0m2.404s
sys     0m0.012s
```

So, the question is, "How efficient is efficient enough"?  Since you didn't specify your requirements, it's really hard for me to know if this algorithm works for you or not.

### The rabbit hole

If you want something faster, here's how I would do it.

Create a VP tree, BK tree, or other suitable spatial index.  For each word in the corpus, insert that word into the tree if it has a suitable minimum distance from every word in the index.  Spatial indexes are specifically designed to support this kind of query.

At the end, you will have a tree containing nodes with the desired minimum distance.

Comment: yes, i think you may be right that i was worrying too much about speed (and a simple solution would suffice).  but then i got interested in the problem for its own sake...

Answer (score 0):

Your trie thought is definitely and interesting one. [This page](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114) has a great setup for fast edit distance calculations in a trie and would definitely be efficient if you needed to expand your wordlist to millions rather than a thousand, which is pretty small in the corpora linguistics business.

Good luck, it sounds like a fun representation of the problem!

Comment: i think the problem here is that the tree saves you time when calculating distances for words spelt similarly.  but what you actually need is something that groups words that *sound* similar, which is not quite the same problem.  that's my understanding of Dietrich's comment above.